# Change onClick function arguments dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<button id="button1" onClick="someFunc('arg1','arg2')"> </button>
```

Is it possible in JavaScript to change parameters of the function `someFunc` to look like below:

```
<button id="button1" onClick="someFunc('somethingDiff1','somethingDiff2')"> </button>
```

Comment: so assign a need onclick method to it and remove the old one.

Comment: or use variables and set those instead

Comment: @epascarello seems a good approach. can you provide an example

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

If you want in jquery then try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var clickfun = $("#button1").attr("onClick");
   var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
   $("#button1").attr("onclick",funname+"('somethingDiff1',"+"'somethingDiff2')");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" onClick="someFunc('arg1','arg2')">Button1</button>
```

If you want in JavaScript then try this:-

```
<script>
  window.onload=function(){
  var clickfun = document.getElementById("button1").getAttribute("onclick");
  var funname = clickfun.substring(0,clickfun.indexOf("("));       
  document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("onclick",funname+"('somethingDiff1',"+"'somethingDiff2')");    
};
</script>
```

Hope This will help you.

Comment: After click the button what about 'someFunc is not defined'

Comment: Terribly easy.... I just did  `$('...').attr("onclick","someFunc('something1','something2')");` and it worked

Answer (score 5):

This could also be done by writing something similiar to this:

```
document.getElementById('button1').setAttribute('onclick','thiswhatyouwanttohave');
```

But the document have to be fully loaded, or at least the button must be present to be able to access the onclick attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this already with some issues. The button is in a table which is generated dynamically.

Comment: ok just wrap it with: window.onload = function () { } to be sure it is accesible, if it works fine also :) you can also set the onload attribute dynamically if this may help

Answer (score 4):

Based on your requirement, we can just change arguments like below: check this working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/TaEgQ/42/

```
button.setAttribute( "onClick", "someFunc('new1','new2')" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just go in your script.js and type something like that:

```
var value = 10

$("#button1").click(function() {

 if(value < 5)
  someFunc("arg1");
 else someFunc("arg2);

});
```